# How to check the length of JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            String url="http://twominenglish.com/api/getlatest?";
             IdArray = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url+"page="+pages);

            mLatestList.clear();
            for(int i=0;i<IdArray.length();i++){
                if(IdArray.isNull(i))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                try{
                     JSONObject jObject;
                     mLtest=new Latest();
                     jObject=IdArray.getJSONObject(i);

                     mLtest.SetID(jObject.getString("ID"));
                     //mLtest.SetImageUrl(jObject.getString("ImageURL"));
                     String path="http://twominenglish.com"+jObject.getString("ImageURL");
                     mLtest.SetImageUrl(path);
                     mLtest.SetDescription(jObject.getString("Description"));
                     mLtest.SetTitle(jObject.getString("Title"));
                     mLatestList.add(mLtest);
                     mLtest=new Latest();

                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can Anyone help me.this is my code where i fetch the data from server through pages like pass the numbers on next button clicked.when it is not feteching data from server how i show the message there is no data..

Comment: your question is unclear to me.

Comment: r u getting response for the same from service?

Comment: You can use [`jsonArray.length()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#length()) method to check the lengght of `JSONArray`, plus you can use android ListView's emptyView option. Have a look at: [Android - Display Alert Dialog for empty ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8265211/593709)

Comment: If you want to know length of the JSON Array then IdArray.length() will do the trick and I can see you are already doing that.

Comment: @ user2012-but it is not getting me answer or not showing the msg also please help me

Comment: @FarhaSameer786 welcome to SO..as Raghunandan said to u ur question is not much cleared...so try to explain ur problems properly and just post relevant code..!

Comment: @Pratik-my prblm is that where i put the code for checking JSONArray is length is empty or not.please help me

Comment: FARHA, the reason you are getting blocked is your questions are very much unclear and confusing, also it is not useful for the community. Please be specific in your questions and avoid "help me" words all of the members are here to share there knowledge and help each other. If you are not good in English please ask to your friend/ colleagues so that they can help you to make a better sentence.

Comment: Also if you get a correct answer for you post, accept it as answer (ticking the tick) it will earn you some stack points also.

Comment: @Jashan PJ-ya sure...i will remember these things..thanks

Answer (score 1):

please give to json array name in your url

like -

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
  ]
}
```

this `jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url+"page="+pages)` function returns a json object .

write the following code

```
// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray IdArray = null;

/ getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

try {
    // Getting Array of Contacts
    IdArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
```

Comment: Maybe you should also point out that `IdArray.length` stores the length of the array result

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code, your JSONArray is

`IdArray = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url+"page="+pages);`

now, immediately after that line, check its length

```
if(IdArray.length()>0)
{
// do all operations here
}
else{
Toast.makeText(mContext, "Array empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps someone doesn't like Simple solutions :P

Answer (score 0):

do in this way...
here is a async class...

class MyTask extends AsyncTask
    {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String result=IOUtils.getUrlResponse(params[0]);

        return result;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
            JSONArray mainJson = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONArray objjson=mainJson.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("data");

     Log.i("lenghth",objjson.length());  //this will return length of Json Array..

}
```